# Avoid wrong version interpolation if child's pom version is different from those of the parent's aggregator pom and its sub modules

Tags: maven, pom.xml, versioning, parent-pom

**Problem description**

We have a Maven aggregator pom with some child poms (modules) all having the same version:

```
pom.xml (parent zoo, version 2.0.0)
|-- pom.xml (child module cat, version 2.0.0)
|-- pom.xml (child module dog, version 2.0.0)
|-- ...
```

Within the dependency management section all children are declared with the project version to ease declaration of dependencies.
The parent pom looks like

```
<groupId>com.acme</groupId>
<artifactId>zoo</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
  <module>cat</module>
  <module>dog</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
      <artifactId>cat</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- other child modules go here -->
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The child poms are defined as

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>zoo</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.acme</groupId>
<artifactId>cat</artifactId>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>dog</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

There is another pom which declares the parent pom as its parent too (inheritance) but is not listed as sub module in this parent (no aggregation). This pom has a different version.

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>zoo</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.acme</groupId>
<artifactId>boo</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>dog</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Actually we have expected that the version of the dependency `com.acme.dog` is pulled from the dependency management section of the parent pom `com.acme.zoo` and is equal to `2.0.0`. However the [Maven documentation on project interpolation and variables](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Interpolation) says

> One factor to note is that these variables are processed after inheritance as outlined above. This means that if a parent project uses a variable, then its definition in the child, not the parent, will be the one eventually used.

That is: in the reactor build the variable `${project.version}` used in the dependency management section of the parent pom `com.acme.zoo` is evaluated with respect to `com.acme.bar` and equal to `1.0.0` what is not as intended.

**Note**

There is a workaround with using a variable in the parent pom which has to be kept in sync with the parent pom versions. However, this solution is incompatible with the [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/).

**Question**

How can we achieve the desired behaviour

- aggregator pom with children having the same version
- declaration of children in the dependency management section to ensure that all dependencies have the same version
- use of inheritance together with different versions
- compatibility with `maven-release-plugin`

without the pitfalls of project interpolation of variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maven release plugin is able to change the versions of the dependencies managed in the parent pom.

So if you define your maven parent like this:

```
<groupId>com.acme</groupId>
<artifactId>zoo</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
  <module>cat</module>
  <module>dog</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
     <artifactId>cat</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- other child modules go here -->
 </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

As you see the versions of the parent and the managed dependency are the same. I set them to a SNAPSHOT version because the release plugin will create the final versions on release:perform

Your child poms can stay as you had them.

Because in your setup, your parent project is also the reactor you can then call

```
mvn release:perform -DautoVersionSubmodules=true
```

which will update the version of the parent in all submodules when you run this command. That option is essentially the same as if you run

```
mvn versions:update-child-modules
```

meaning it will change the child poms.

After you run the mvn release:perform command your parent pom will look like this:

```
<groupId>com.acme</groupId>
<artifactId>zoo</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
  <module>cat</module>
  <module>dog</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
     <artifactId>cat</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- other child modules go here -->
 </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and your child poms like this

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>zoo</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.acme</groupId>
<artifactId>cat</artifactId>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>dog</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The final versions will only exist in the tag created by the release:prepare command.

PS: You may define other versions for the final and the next development version when they are prompted after running the release:prepare command.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is modify pom of zoo and replace `<version>${project.version}</version>` with `<version>2.0.0</version>`

Please note:

1. when you change version to next number, for example 2.0.1, with
   `versions-maven-plugin`, dependency management section will be also
   updated.
2. Spring use simplest solution, see
   http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/4.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-bom-4.2.7.RELEASE.pom

Summary: using `<version>${project.version}</version>` in dependency management is wrong idea.

Answer (score 0):

From Maven Introduction to the pom : http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

**Project Inheritance > Example 1 > The Solution**

> Alternatively, if we want the groupId and / or the version of your
>   modules to be the same as their parents, you can remove the groupId
>   and / or the version identity of your module in its POM.
>
> ```
> <project>
>   <parent>
>     <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
>     <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
>     <version>1</version>
>   </parent>
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <artifactId>my-module</artifactId>
> </project>
> ```

Comment: The problem is that `cat` must depend on `dog` of the same version. For that dependecy management is applied. You answer does not solve problem with dependency management configuration

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean now. In this case you could have cat version 1.1 that has a parent 1.0 so the version of dog would be 1.0. And this is wrong.

Comment: Your hint to remove version from cat and dog  is fine, but the problem is different. Actually whole zoo has version 2.0.0 and question owner want cat depend on dog without version defined in cat's `pom.xml`. For that reason version of dog is defined in zoo dependency management section. But the version is defined as `${project.version}` and it is wrong

Answer (score 0):

My approach to that is to track it in the child POM.  It's a bit less typing overall, close to where the actual dependency lives and is low maintenance for most projects.  YMMV

```
<dependencies>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-sibling</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```